# In Glass shader, transparency in not displayed

Tags: rendering, shaders, transparency

I want that when I apply glass shader then transparency must display but it is not , when I applied glass shader then reflection of trees are dipplayed instead of transparency , why? please help me, I am using blender 2.8, this problem is in both cyclic and EVEE

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tj6MgfhqOr4